# Is there a nix configuration file for the normal user?

Tags: nixos

In setting up NixOS (as of 22.11), I wanted to add Emacs to the system `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`, so that it's always in the OS by default. In order to edit the system configuration with Emacs, I had to install Emacs first with:

```
nix-env -i emacs
```

As expected, after editing the `environment.systemPackages`and a `nixos-rebuild` command, I have emacs in the OS and the next time I rebuild nixos, Emacs will be there (even if I `nix-env --uninstall emacs`).

Now, the question is, the stuff I installed with `nix-env -i` isn't reflected in the `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` file. Since it's executed in the command line, these locally installed command set isn't very reproducible. (The same is true for the configurations that I will add in `~/.emacs.d`)

My question is:

Is there a way to make local installs (e.g. `emacs` here) or local configurations (e.g. `.emacs.d`) also reproducible through a configuration file?

Comment: To manage per-user profile and dotfiles there's
https://github.com/nix-community/home-manager

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend using `nix-env -i` to install any software, to make sure the system is reproducible, all system changes should be made by editing `nixos-configuration.nix`.

As for the configuration of emacs, it is recommended to modify it through home-manager.

If there are few configurations, you can manage them directly through [home manager - `programs.emacs.extraConfig`](https://nix-community.github.io/home-manager/options.xhtml#opt-programs.emacs.extraConfig)).

If there are many configurations, it is recommended to use [home manager  - `home.file.<name>.source`](https://nix-community.github.io/home-manager/options.xhtml#opt-home.file._name_.source) for management.

To make the system more reproducible, I would recommend using NixOS with Flakes, here is a guide for that:

https://github.com/ryan4yin/nixos-and-flakes-book

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The first two links are 404. Can you fix them?

Answer (score 0):

Using nix-env to install packages for the system is not recommended. If you want to add packages to your system for all users, [check this portion of the manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nixos/stable/index.html#sec-package-management). In short, you edit your configuration.nix to have:

```
environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    <your package here>
]
```

Then, if you want to edit the configuration for it, you can [visit this website](https://search.nixos.org/options) to see the options for that package. For example, in vim's case, an example config would be:

```
programs.vim = {
    enable = true;
    defaultEditor = true;
};
```

This way, you can have your entire configuration be declarative. If you want to have per-user programs and configs, you can follow the guide in @Vladimír Čunát's comment for home-manager. It's a little extra setup, but it's very similar to the way to install things for the entire system. Home-manager also has some extra options for some packages, so be sure to check them in the home-manager manual, [one of which can be found here.](https://mipmip.github.io/home-manager-option-search/)